# Update all values for given key nested in JSON array of objects

Tags: postgresql, update, json, postgresql-10, json-path

I have a `jsonb` column `data` in a Postgres table `my_table`. It contains the following data:

```
[
   {"id":"1","status":"test status1","updatedAt":"1571145003"},
   {"id":"2","status":"test status2","updatedAt":"1571145323"}
]
```

I want to update the `updatedAt` key of all objects in that array using one query. I tried:

```
update my_table set data = data || '{"updatedAt": "1571150000"}';
```

The above query added a new object within the array like the following:

```
[
   {"id":"1","status":"test status1","updatedAt":"1571145003"},
   {"id":"2","status":"test status2","updatedAt":"1571145323"},
   {"updatedAt":"1571150000"}
]
```

I want the output like:

```
[
   {"id":"1","status":"test status1","updatedAt":"1571150000"},
   {"id":"2","status":"test status2","updatedAt":"1571150000"}
]
```

I also tried `jsonb_set()`, but that needs the second parameter to be the array index. I can't be sure of the count of JSON objects in the array.

If this can be solved with custom functions, also fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First cte unnest all elements of the array, second one update each element and then simply update the original table building the array again.

```
with ct as
(
    select id, jsonb_array_elements(data) dt
    from   t
)
, ct2 as
(
  select id, jsonb_set(dt, '{updatedAt}', '"1571150000"', false) dt2
  from   ct
)
update t
set    data = (select jsonb_agg(dt2) from ct2 where ct2.id = t.id);
```

> ```
> select * from t;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | data                                                                                                                                
> -: | :-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | [{"id": "1", "status": "test status1", "updatedAt": "1571150000"}, {"id": "2", "status": "test status2", "updatedAt": "1571150000"}]
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=349e15b2f5075d4d524a438e318618b1)*

Answer (score 6):

You declared Postgres 10, for which McNets provided a valid solution. It should be slightly more efficient without CTEs as those cannot be inlined before Postgres 12:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    data = (
   SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(d, '{updatedAt}', '"15711500000"', false))
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(data) d
   );
```

[`jsonb_set()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) is handy, but the operation is still **inefficient** while some rows don't actually *need* an update. This query writes a new version for very row. See:

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/28vSV5Wu)

It's (much) more efficient to only update rows that actually change. Better yet, identify those with index support to begin with. Not trivial in Postgres 10 (would require a tailored expression index). Much simpler and more efficient since [**Postgres 12** with the **SQL/JSON** path language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH):

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    data = (
   SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(dt, '{updatedAt}', '"15711500000"', false))
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(data) dt
   )
WHERE  data @? '$.updatedAt ? (@ != "1571150000")';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FlhKOpmi)

The added `WHERE  data @? '$.updatedAt ? (@ != "1571150000")'` basically says:

*'Look at the key "updatedAt" (in all array elements) at the top level and check whether any of them is not equal to "1571150000"; return true if (and only if) such a key is found.'*

Identifies qualifying rows with index support. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING)

> Also, GIN index supports `@@` and `@?` operators, which perform `jsonpath` matching.

`!=` is harder to support than `==`. But index support can still make a *huge* difference.