# How to sum the values ​of a json column filtered with regex?

Tags: postgresql, json, regex, json-path

How to sum the values ​​of a json column filtered with regex?

Columns:

`A.name`: *Varchar with name product*

`B.products`: *JSON with time active By product*

Query:

```
select
    A.name as product,
    sum(((REGEXP_MATCH(B.products->>'status', 'Active:.(.*?)\"'))[1])::float) as metric
from
    tbl_accounts A
inner join tbl_products B on
    A.identifier = B.identifier
where
    B.products->>'status' like '%Active%'
group by
    A.name,
    B.products
```

Explanation data

**JSON 1:** `{"times": ["Stoped: 49.05", "Active: 23.26"]}`

**JSON 2:** `{"times": ["Stoped: 59.05", "Active: 33.26"]}`

**Desired Output:** `56.52`

Output:

> ```
> ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type json
> ```

Comment: It's so much easier to answer if you provide your version of Postgres and proper table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements). And a minimal, correct data sample. Ideally, a fiddle. ([Random example.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=cb270cbcb45a63478a8a62bf7137c634))

Comment: I will try to model a data, I have to be careful with the disclosure, corporate data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate reason for the error message is that the data type `json` has no equality operator. See:

- [How to query a json column for empty objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24296054/939860)
- [How to remove known elements from a JSON[] array in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64759/how-to-remove-known-elements-from-a-json-array-in-postgresql/64765#64765)

You have:

```sql
...
group by
    A.name,
    B.products  -- type json!?
```

You *can* do that, using **`jsonb`** instead of `json`, where an equality operator is defined. But do you really want to group by `B.products`? (Same JSON documents?) Maybe you meant to write `B.products->>'status'` (Same status?) Or just `GROUP BY A.name`?

Aside: there may also be a simpler way to extract numbers that with `REGEXP_MATCH()`. You would have to define possible values `B.products->>'status'` and disclose the exact intention of the expression.

If you are at liberty to do so, it's typically best to store numbers in a separate key or even separate table column ....

### [`jsonpath`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) query in Postgres 12 or later

Your added sample values suggest you might be able to use `jsonpath` in Postgres 12 or later. Based on `jsonb` (not `json`).

**Note:** this is a proof of concept. If possible, normalize the table design and store numbers in a dedicated table column. Much simpler and more efficient.

#### Index

`jsonpath` operators can also be supported with a (default) `jsonb_ops` GIN index. I narrow down the scope with the expression `products->'times'`:

```
CREATE INDEX products_times_gin_idx ON products USING gin ((products->'times'));
```

Index only helps for *selective* queries where not most rows have to be processed anyways!

#### Basic query to filter qualifying rows with `jsonpath`

Can use above index.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   products B
WHERE  B.products->'times' @? '$[*] ? (@ starts with "Active: ")';
```

`jsonpath` expression explained:

`$[*]` ... look at each array element of outer nesting level
`?` ... run the following test
`(@ starts with "Active: ")` ... Does element value start with 'Active:'?

#### ... unnest and return only qualifying JSON array elements

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   accounts A
JOIN   products B USING (identifier)
     , jsonb_path_query(B.products->'times', '$[*] ? (@ starts with "Active: ")') act
WHERE  B.products->'times' @? '$[*] ? (@ starts with "Active: ")' -- optional, to use idx
;
```

#### ...  get results as text

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   accounts A
JOIN   products B USING (identifier)
     , jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb_path_query_array(B.products->'times', '$[*] ? (@ starts with "Active: ")')) act
WHERE  B.products->'times' @? '$[*] ? (@ starts with "Active: ")' -- optional, to use idx
;
```

See:

- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array/54289#54289)

#### ... and aggregate the number part

Arriving at your final query:

```sql
SELECT A.name as product, sum(right(act::text, -8)::float)  -- -8 = length('Active: ')
FROM   accounts A
JOIN   products B USING (identifier)
     , jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb_path_query_array(B.products->'times', '$[*] ? (@ starts with "Active: ")')) act
WHERE  B.products->'times' @? '$[*] ? (@ starts with "Active: ")' -- optional, to use idx
GROUP  BY 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7f0dedfb2a969d3aa19d9b2e4d4c0b5e)*

Related:

- [Update all values for given key nested in JSON array of objects](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/251133/update-all-values-for-given-key-nested-in-json-array-of-objects/251181#251181)

Comment: I liked your explanation, I'll try something with `jsonb`

Comment: @LuisHenrique: You already accepted. But consider the added jsonpath solution.

Comment: Of course, I will look, thank you very much!